# Uniqueness of positive-definite subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

> Let $g$ be a bilinear form over $\mathbb{R}^8$ with signature $(5,3)$.
>
> True or false - There exists a unique five dimensional subspace such that $g$ is positive-definite on this subspace.

My intuition says it is true, and that the subspace is a span of five vectors which make the five $+1$ in the representation matrix, but after proving existence, I am stuck with uniqueness. So far what I have concluded:

There exists a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_8$ such that $g(v_i,v_j) = \delta_{i,j},\ i,j\leq5$, $g(v_i,v_j) = -\delta_{i,j},\ 6\leq i,j\leq 8$. Suppose there is another 5 dimensional subspace such that $g$ is positive-definite on this subspace. We know for sure that $v_6,v_7,v_8$ are not in this subspace.

I have tried to show that a vector in this subspace is in the span I mentioned above, but no success.

Any suggestions? Is the statement even true?

Thanks

Comment: Consider the form $(x,y) \mapsto x^2 - y^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. For which $t$ is the restriction to the space spanned by $(1,t)$ positive definite, zero, negative definite?

Comment: source of the problem? Book you might be reading????

Comment: No, just an exercise I got at my linear algebra class homework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restriction of the form to the subspace $\langle e_1, \ldots, e_5\rangle$ is positive, indeed the matrix of the form is $I_5$. Wiggle a bit the the $e_i$, $i=1,5$ to $e'_i$. The matrix of the form $( (e'_i, e'_j))_{1 \le i,j \le 5}$ changes a bit so for small variations it remains positive definite. Hence for $e'_i$ close to $e_i$ the restriction to $\langle e'_1, \ldots e'_5\rangle$ is still positive definite ( one can provide some effective estimates).

Comment: So you say that if, for example, I choose $v_1+tv_6,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$, $0<t<1$, for every $t$ the form will be positive-definite on this span?

Comment: @JonTrav: That's a very good choice! Make it  $t \in (-1,1)$.You can also choose $v_2 + s v_7$, $v_3 + r v_8$ instead of $v_2$, $v_3$.

Comment: I understand that the restriction to $\langle e'_1, \ldots e'_5\rangle$ is positive definite. But how does this answer the question?

Comment: As far as I understand, we want to show that if $v_1,\ldots,v_5$ are linearly independent and the restriction to $\langle v_1,\ldots,v_5\rangle$ is positive definite, then $\langle v_1,\ldots,v_5\rangle=\langle e_1,\ldots,e_5\rangle$ and I don't understand how that is related to your answer.

Comment: @Filippo: The spaces spanned for different $t$'s are different. Can you check that?  Indeed, the ratio of the $6$-th  and $1$-st coordinates are $t$ for vectors in that subspace $V_t$.

Comment: @orangeskid Now I understand the idea of the proof, thank you very much :) So the "Intuition" of the OP was wrong and there is not a unique five dimensional subspace such that $g$ is positive-definite on this subspace.

Comment: @orangeskid In retrospect, I guess it should have been intuitively clear (from smaller dimensions) that the spans of $e$ and $e'$ are in general not equal. (+1) for your answer.