# Is a scalar product positive definite on a unique maximal subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space and
\begin{equation}
\eta\colon V\times V\to\mathbb R
\end{equation}
a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form. [Sylvester’s Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) allows us to consider the natural number $r\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$ defined as the maximum dimension among all subspaces on which the restriction of $\eta$ is positive definite.

**Question**: Can there be two different $r$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ such that the restriction of $\eta$ to them is positive-definite? ([Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1331896/572841) is a related question.)

**Motivation**: I am currently studying special relativity and I was wondering if the tangent (translation) space has a unique decomposition as the direct sum of $1$-dimensional and a $3$-dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Consider $n=2$, and $\eta(x,y) = x_1y_1-x_2y_2$. Then clearly $r=1$, and $\eta$ is positive definite over e.g. $\text{span}\{(1,0)\}$ and $\text{span}\{(2,1)\}$.

From a different point of view, there might be more than one way to diagonalize a matrix $\eta$ through $\eta\mapsto A^t \eta A$.

In terms of General Relativity, this is exactly the point: You cannot distinguish a space coordinate from a time one. Even in Special Relativity, when you do a Lorentz transformation, space and time coordinates are mixed.